# ML.Net and how to make K-Means deterministic?

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am new to machine learning and ML.NET and try to use K-Means for price clustering.
This is the code I have and my main issue is that every time I run the code I get different centroids.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello Clustring!");
   var mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 4);
                
   IDataView trainData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SwingHighLow> 
   (_dataPath,hasHeader:true,separatorChar: ';');                      
                
   string featuresColumnName = "Features";
   var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms                
   .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "Price")                
   .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, numberOfClusters: 4));                            
               
    
   var model = pipeline.Fit(trainData);   
    
   VBuffer<float>[] centroids = default;            
                
   var modelParams = model.LastTransformer.Model;
   modelParams.GetClusterCentroids(ref centroids, out int k);
   Console.WriteLine(
      $"The first centroid is: " +
      string.Join(", ", centroids[0].GetValues().ToArray().Take(3)));
    
      Console.WriteLine(
      $"The second centroid is: " +
      string.Join(", ", centroids[1].GetValues().ToArray()[0]));                
    
      Console.WriteLine(
      $"The third centroid is: " +
      string.Join(", ", centroids[2].GetValues().ToArray().Take(3)));
    
    
      Console.WriteLine(
      $"The fourth centroid is: " +
      string.Join(", ", centroids[3].GetValues().ToArray().Take(3)));
    
}
```

What can I do to get always the same result for the same input data. I read that setting the seed could solve the problem but somehow this does not work for me. Any suggestios?

Thank you,
Anton